# Autoincrementing field in typed dataset

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm using typed dataset and trying to update a table with one autoincrementing column.
The problem is that when I update this table in the following manner

```
        tableAdapter.DeleteAllQuery();//
            DataRow addedRow =  dataTable.Rows.Add(null,
                                                dev.No,
                                                dev.IdKat.ToString());
        string id = addedRow.[0].ToString();
        tableAdapter.Update(dataTable);
```

autoincrementing field `id` is not the same as it is in database. For example `addedRow.[0].ToString()` returns `0` but in the database the value is `2`.

To get actual `id` value I'm doing this trick

```
    tableAdapter.DeleteAllQuery();//
        DataRow addedRow =  dataTable.Rows.Add(null,
                                            dev.No,
                                            dev.IdKat.ToString());
    **tableAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    tableAdapter.Fill(dataTable);**     
    string id = addedRow.[0].ToString();
    tableAdapter.Update(dataTable);
```

And everything works fine. But filling my datatable after every insert/update operation is a time consuming task. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found it in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)